# PIC24F read-after-write (stall case)

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

[image: Datasheet with Highlight]

Device: PIC24FJ256GB110

I am not getting the highlighted part.  Why it is "Allowed"?

The reference manual says:

> **Read-After-Write Dependency Rules**
>
> If a working register, Wn, is used as a write operation destination in the current instruction, and the same working register, Wn, being read in the prefetched instruction are the same, the following rules will apply:
>
> 1. If the destination write (current instruction) does not modify the contents of Wn, no stalls will occur; or
> 2. If the source read (prefetched instruction) does not calculate an EA using Wn, no stalls will occur.

Answer (score 1):

It falls into case 2) of the reference material you cited. The value of W2 is used directly in the second instruction, and it is not being used to calculate an address of an operand. (EA means "effective address".)

The reason this works is (probably) because the CPU includes "forwarding" logic for the specific purpose of avoiding a stall in this common scenario.

Comment: What about case 1
the 1st instruction is writing into W2..and the second instruction is using data from W2..
Destination write is modifying the contents of Wn

Comment: That's exactly the case we're talking about here.